# How to execute code when a div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, execute

I've spent the last few hours trying to find the answer to this, but nothing seems to work...

I need to execute a piece of code when a div (or anything inside of it; including iframe content) is clicked. The following code should do it (when added into the div tag), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
onclick="if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) =='function'){ _vis_opt_goal_conversion(200); _vis_opt_pause(500);}"
```

The purpose is to execute a custom conversion goal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == "function") {
   _vis_opt_goal_conversion(200);
   }
</script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You googled this and couldn't find anything?

Comment: Personally I hate putting all the code in the onclick. Make a function called `function testfunction(){alert('test');}` and then call that function on click. This is to make sure it's firing. Then you can more easily debug your issu.e

Comment: It won't/can't work if the click was inside the iframed document.

Answer (score 1):

I hate using inline js... hate it...

If you need to account for IE (<8), then you can't use addEventListener, so you can do something like this:

```
function bindListener(el,eventName,eventHandler) {
    if (el.addEventListener) { // Anything but IE <8
        el.addEventListener(eventName,eventHandler,false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) { // For IE <8
        el.attachEvent('on'+eventName,eventHandler);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it using something like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('idOfElement');

bindListener(ele, 'click', functionToCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using addEventListener. [Link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener).  The [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener#Example) on that page is exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I write simple example for you:(j Query answer)

**Html Code**

```
<div class="test">Click</div>
```

**JavaScript  Code**

```
$('div.test').click(function(){
    alert("some");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xD8Xq/)

**Edited**

JavaScript example

```
<html >
<script type="text/javascript">
function AttachAllDivEvents()
{
var divCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0; i<divCollection.length; i++)
{
AttachDivClickEvent(divCollection[i]);
}
}
function AttachDivClickEvent(divObj)
{
divObj.onclick = function()
{
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").innerHTML) + 1;
};
}
window.onload = AttachAllDivEvents;
</script>

<body>
<div>click</div>
<p id="count" style="font:bold 20px Times;color:red;text-indent:20px">1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First give your `div` a unique ID

```
<div id="yourDivID"></div>
```

then set the onclick function in `window.onload`

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("yourDivID");

yourDiv.onclick = function() {
       if(typeof(_vis_opt_top_initialize) == "function") {
           _vis_opt_goal_conversion(200);
       }
   }
}
```